# Unable to change make a dynamic search with Soundcloud API

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm having problems getting this code to work. I can do a static search using the 'q', 'bpm' or 'genres' parameters in SC.get(). However when I try to make it dynamic with a variable ('category')...the values are passed off correctly but the performed search doesn't match.:

```
function getTracks(){
    query = document.getElementById('search').value;
    category = document.getElementById('category').value;

    SC.get('/tracks', { category : query}, function(tracks) { 
                console.log(query);
        console.log(category);
            ... rest of search code
            }
```

Inside HTML:

```
        <form>
            Search by Title: <input type="text" name = "search" id = "search">
                            <select id = "category">
                            <option value = "genres">Genre</option>
                            <option value = "q">Title</option>
                            <option value = "bpm">BPM</option>
                            </select>

        <input type="button" onclick = "getTracks()" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

Is there something I'm missing? Console.log catches the correct values for both 'search' and 'category' values but the API is returning as if they are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the `{ category: query }` is assigning `category` as a key name, not taking the variable `category` and assigning that as the key name. This is a bit of an inconsistency in Javascript.

You want to do this:

```
parameters = {};
parameters[category] = query

SC.get('/tracks', parameters, function(tracks…
```

Comment: There's also no such parameter as `category` in SoundCloud API

Comment: Thank you, I didn't recognize the hash! This works wonderfully.